# Ubuntu 14.04 Dell XPS15 HDMI Not Detected

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, screen, hdmi

After some actualization my HDMI died. Can someone help me ?

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 
Dell XPS15 l502x
Graphic Driver X.org X server - Noveau

-- On system config / displays .::. only appears the integrated screen, and if I connect hdmi -> detect screens nothing happens.

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1366 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       59.6*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

lspci | grep VGA 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)

uname -r
3.13.0-34-generic
```

I tried to install Nvidia proprietary drivers (304, 331 and 342) but they doesn't work (I get black screen), so I use Nouveau for now.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "after some actualization my HDMI died"? Did you ever got it working under linux?

I've had this exact same laptop for a while now and searching over the years I've learned that HDMI support for this hardware is almost nonexistent under linux due to it being indirectly wired through the Nvidia  card (Optimus Hybrid Graphics). The most promising workaround I've found involves firing two simultaneous sessions (one with each video card). The problem is this two sessions do not share applications in real time and you don't get any sound from the HDMI output.

You can check all about it here: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html

Also here, if you use bumblebee (you totally should): https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

The second best option is using the mini display port output which is connected directly to the integrated graphics card. There are plenty of HDMI adaptors that are dirty cheap (if that's what you need).

If anyone have other information I'm not aware of, please do share!

Comment: As you say always I get it working without sound, At the past, I saw 3 monitors on my system configuration: the integrated screen, a virtual screen and the 3rd was the HDMI. For the short time I've been with this laptop it works with 2 monitors ans I could drag applications between the 2 monitors and make normal things, in the last weeks I made the suggested upgrades and lose the HDMI, I can't see the 3 screens on system config, just one (the integrated) .... Then I guess,  always I had working both cards simultaneously. I will try the second method that you share and will post the results.